# compare 2 fields and get first valid values else get any one value in excel

Tags: excel

Hi I have doubt in excel
how to compare 2 fields and get first valide values else get any one value in excel
empid and empid_1 compare and fill values in expected reuslt.
[image]

please tell me how to achive this task in excel.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share a sample data in order to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: Empid Fild and EMPid_1 filed need to compare and fill values in C Column.in the screen shot is sample data (A,B) and Expected values in C.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this formula in C2 and drag down as you need it:

```
=IF(ISERROR(A2),B2,A2)
```